# Merge with Insert/Update with recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let say I have 2 tables,

```
DECLARE @BaseProducts TABLE (Id int)
DECLARE @ConnectData TABLE (Id int, ACTION varchar(10))
```

I have some data in @ConnectData,

```
INSERT INTO @ConnectData (Id, ACTION)
VALUES (1, 'Insert')
INSERT INTO @ConnectData (Id, ACTION)
VALUES (1, 'Insert')
INSERT INTO @ConnectData (Id, ACTION)
VALUES (1, 'Insert')
```

Now i want to update @BaseProduct from @ConnectData, so I tried

```
MERGE @BaseProducts AS D
USING (SELECT Id, ACTION FROM @ConnectData) S 
    ON D.Id = S.Id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(Id)
    VALUES(S.Id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
        SET Id = S.Id;
```

But this is inserting 3 rows. I want the first one should be insert and other 2 should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching this problem in wrong way, Merge statement should have `MATCHED` case before `NOT MATCHED`.

What you are trying to do here `MERGE Statement` isnt the right tool. You should be doing a distinct insert something like this..

Also dont the see the point of Updating ID with ID since both values are same (hence you joined on them).

```
INSERT INTO @BaseProducts (Id)
SELECT t.Id
FROM @ConnectData t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM @BaseProducts
                  WHERE ID = t.Id)
GROUP BY t.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

MERGE doesn't act up on the newly inserted rows by MERGE itself.

To accomplish what you need,

you need to insert distinct values based on NOT MATCHED to the empty table

```
MERGE @BaseProducts AS D
USING (SELECT distinct Id, ACTION FROM @ConnectData) S 
    ON D.Id = S.Id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(Id)
    VALUES(S.Id);
```

you can do another MERGE to update based on MATCHED Condition

```
MERGE @BaseProducts AS D
USING (SELECT distinct Id, ACTION FROM @ConnectData) S 
    ON D.Id = S.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
        SET Id = S.Id;
```